# How to break an inline math equation?

Tags: alignment

I am rewriting proofs and encountered a long inline equation. However, I can't break the equation so that it is still aligned within the proof environment. Is there a direct code that I can use to solve my problem? I tried using \allowbreak inside $ . . . $ and ( . . . ), and \parbox but it all did nothing. This is what my code looks like:

```
\begin{document} 
\begin{proof}[\textbf{Proof}]
Let $O_n = \big\{ x \in X : \exists \text{ a neighborhood } U \text{ of } x \text{ such that }  U \cap E \neq \emptyset \text{ and the diameter of }  f[U \cap E] \text{ is less than } 1/n \big\}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to start and stop math here instead of using `\text`

Comment: im math `\text` is mbox so can not break and the spaces do not stretch to help justify paragraphs, replace all the `\text{ and the diameter of }` by ending math then having teh text `\and the diameter of` in the main paragraph then start math again.

Comment: thanks for your comments! I figured it how now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested in comments, you may want to write the text of the proof primarily in text mode, with the various math-y expressions rendered in inline math mode. E.g., something like this (I probably didn't use the most felicitous possibilities):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document} 
\begin{proof}[\textbf{\upshape Proof}]
Let $O_n$ be the set $\{ x \in X \}$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap E \neq \emptyset$ and the diameter of $f[U \cap E]$ is less than $1/n$. \dots
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid long set descriptions in the set-builder notation, especially if there are words in them: readers would have a hard time in deciphering it, as the braces are not that prominent in normal text.

You should also avoid abusing the optional argument to `proof` in order to set formatting options. Unfortunately, `amsthm` still doesn't provide for such a feature, but it's easy to patch `proof` to this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\proofnamefont}{}{}
\newcommand{\proofnamefont}{\normalfont\itshape\bfseries} % or whatever you like

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Let $O_n$ be the set of all $x\in X$ with the property that there exists 
a neighborhood $U$ of~$x$ such that $U \cap E \neq \emptyset$ and the 
diameter of $f[U \cap E]$ is less than~$1/n$.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]